# How to pre-train or finetune LLM with structured dataset, so the LLM can reason the relationships between data objects

Tags: large-language-model

I want to train LLM with structured dataset such as database with multiple tables. Here is an simple example:
t_user:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jason |
| 2 | Eric |
| 3 | David |

t_book:

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Gone with The Wind |
| 2 | Brave New World |
| 3 | Native Son |

t_bookstore:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | The Book Nook |
| 2 | The Literary Loft |
| 3 | Wordsmith Books |

t_order:

| user_id | bookstore_id | book_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 |

After training the LLM, it can reason on this relational database. Such as when I ask:
how many books did **Jason** buy in **The Literary Loft** bootstore? It can answers: 2 books, **Gone with The Wind** and **Brave New World**.

How can I prepare the corpus from the database and train the LLM ?

I have searched for some solutions, such as ask the LLM to transform prompts to sql queries, but that's not what I want.

Comment: You shouldn't use an LLM to directly manipulate data in a database, it will always be unpredictable and unreliable, since the goal of an LLM is to interpret and transform data. What you CAN do is transform a user's loose text input to an exact command that can be executed in your system. For example, a user could say "Hey, what books did Jason buy?", and then the LLM can learn to execute the function `getBooks("jason")`. To learn how to do this you can look at the "functions" documentation in the OpenAI API.

Comment: @Kokodoko Thanks for your answer! If I convert my database to other format, such as json/csv (use special fields to express the relationship between data objects), and train the LLM. Does LLM has the ability to extract the relationships?

Comment: Yes you can convert your database tables to a text document. Then, you can convert it to a "text embedding". This means the data is transformed to a vector format (look at "embeddings" in the OpenAI documentation). Once you have your embeddings, you can use a LLM to ask questions to your document, for example, "what books did jason buy". Of course your tables have to be glued together from all the relational database tables (it won't learn the relationships just by using the table id's).

Comment: @Kokodoko Thanks again! Do you know are there any cases that other people have 
 already done this so that I can refer to, or the best appropriate text format which I convert database tables to, so the LLM can learn better?

Comment: You'll have to experiment a bit, that's what everyone is doing at the moment with LLMs! Try to create a text file, make an embedding, and then use a LLM to read it. But I have to say, if you really want to use AI to learn database data, an LLM is not the best choice. LLMs are really meant for using language as an interface, but not for actually learning exact data.

Comment: You can read all about embeddings here: https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/embeddings

Comment: @Kokodoko Got it, appreciate your answer!